# Webpack require won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

So I have this code, using jQuery...

```
require("./locations.js");
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log("Adding locations..");
        $.each(locations, function(key,loc) {
          if (loc.popular == 1) $(".popular-list").append("<a href='#'><li class='loc'>Hello</li></a>");
        });

        $.ajax({
            url : "changelog.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".the-log").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
```

and `locations.js` contains this:

```
var locations = [
{ name: "Varrocka", lng: 22.5, lat: -15.52249812756166, popular: 1 },
{ name: 'Lumbridge', lng: -43.644025847699496, lat: 25.9661865234375, popular: 1 },
{ name: "Monastery", lng: -4.0924072265625, lat: -5.714379819235291 },
{ name: "Edgeville", lng: 2.4884033203125, lat: -6.0094592380595495, popular: 1 },
{ name: "Varrock Palace", lng: 22.412109375, lat: -6.882800241767556 },
{ name: "Digsite", lng: 46.043701171875, lat: -17.266727823520508 }
];
```

However, on the `$.each` line on the first code block above, there's this error that happens:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: locations is not defined`

Now, I thought I just initalized it... this is my `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/js/main.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: "bundle.js"
    }
};
```

and `bundle.js` and `locations.js` are on the same directory as they are stored on `js/bundle.js` and `js/locations.js` respetively.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to export something from `locations.js`, like

```
module.exports = [
    { name: "Varrocka", lng: 22.5, lat: -15.52249812756166, popular: 1 },
    ...
];
```

Then use it as

```
var locations = require("./locations.js");;
```

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed it where you had to wrap everythinf around `module.exports[]`